# SOLR Tika: add text of file to existing record (ExtractingRequestHandler)

Tags: solr, full-text-search, apache-tika, solr-cell

I am indexing posts in SOLR with "name", "title", and "description" fields. I'd like to later be able to add a file (like a Word doc or a PDF) using Tika / the ExtractingRequestHandler.

I know I can add documents like so: (or through other interfaces)

> curl
>   'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=**post1**&commit=true'
>   -F "myfile=@tutorial.html"

But this replaces the correct post (post1 above) -- is there a parameter I can pass to have it only add to the record?

Answer (score 6):

In Solr (ver < 4.0) you can't modify fields in a document. You can only delete or add/replace whole documents. Therefore, when "appending" a file to the Solr document you have to rebuild your document from its current values (using `literal`), i.e. query for the document and then:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=post1&literal.name=myName&literal.title=myTitle&literal.description=myDescription&commit=true
```

Comment: This curl request may be too long (there may be many field values that I want to append alongwith the file contents). Is there a way to get the contents of the file and then add it to the solr document and then commit the whole document?

Comment: @ptokya that's a question about `curl` rather than Solr. You should create a new, specific question about that.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: Here's my full specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609690/index-pdf-file-content-using-apache-solr