# Index pdf file content using Apache Solr

Tags: php, solr, apache-tika

I'm using Solr's [php extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) for interacting with Apache Solr. I'm indexing data from the database. I wanted to index contents of external files (like PDFs, PPTX) as well.

The logic for indexing is:
Suppose the `schema.xml` has the following fields defined:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="created" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="filepath" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="filecontent" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

A single database entry may/may not have a file stored.

Hence, following is my code for indexing:

```
$post = stdclass object having the database content
$doc = new SolrInputDocument();
$doc->addField('id', $post->id);
$doc->addField('name', $post->name);
....
....
$res = $client->addDocument($doc);
$client->commit();
```

Next, I want to add the contents of the PDF file in the same solr document as above.

This is the `curl` code:

```
$ch = curl_init('
http://localhost:8010/solr/update/extract?');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('myfile'=>'@'.$post->filepath));
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
```

But, I guess I'm missing something. I read the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler), but I cannot figure out a way of retrieving the contents of the file and then adding it to the existing solr document in the `field: filecontent`

**EDIT #1**:
If I try to set `literal.id=xyz` in the curl request, it creates a new solr document having `id=xyz`. I don't want a new solr document created. I want the contents of the pdf to be indexed and stored as a field in the previously created solr document.

```
$doc = new SolrInputDocument();//Solr document is created
$doc->addField('id', 98765);//The solr document created above is assigned an id=`98765`
....
....
$ch = curl_init('
http://localhost:8010/solr/update/extract?literal.id=1&literal.name=Name&commit=true');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('myfile'=>'@'.$post->filepath));
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
```

I want the above solr document (`id = 98765`) to have a field in which the contents of the pdf get indexed & stored.

But the cURL request (as above) creates another new document (with `id = 1`). I don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

Solr with Apache Tika does the handling of extracting the Contents of the Rich Documents and adding it back to the Solr document.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Getting_Started_with_the_Solr_Example) :-

> You may notice that although you can search on any of the text in the
>   sample document, you may not be able to see that text when the
>   document is retrieved. This is simply because the "content" field
>   generated by Tika is mapped to the Solr field called "text", which is
>   indexed but not stored. This is done via the default map rule in the
>   /update/extract handler in solrconfig.xml and can be easily changed or
>   overridden. For example, to store and see all metadata and content,
>   execute the following:

Default schema.xml :-

```
<!-- Main body of document extracted by SolrCell.
    NOTE: This field is not indexed by default, since it is also copied to "text"
    using copyField below. This is to save space. Use this field for returning and
    highlighting document content. Use the "text" field to search the content. -->
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

If you are defining a different attribute for maintaining the file contents override the default with `fmap.content=filecontent` in the solrconfig.xml itself.

> The fmap.content=attr_content param overrides the default
>   fmap.content=text causing the content to be added to the attr_content
>   field instead.

If you want to index it in a single documment use literal prefix e.g. `literal.id=1&literal.name=Name` with the attributes

```
$ch = curl_init('
http://localhost:8010/solr/update/extract?literal.id=1&literal.name=Name&commit=true');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('myfile'=>'@'.$post->filepath));
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I'be done indexing. Searching is also successful. When executing the curl command as given in the wiki,  it adds it as a "new" Solr Document. `curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true" -F "myfile=@tutorial.html"` -> this command adds a new solr doc having `id=doc1`, indexes content from `tutorial.html` and commits it. I want to add the content of the html/pdf as a field in an earlier defined solr doc, so that a "new" document is not created, but a field is added to an existing one.

Comment: Do you want to add multiple rich documents to a single Solr document ? Solr does not allow multiple rich documents with a Single document but you can zip the documents together and feed it to solr. Check SOLR-2332. Also you can check Solr partial updates to feed document to solr which the add to the multivalued field.

Comment: No. Not multiple docs. `$doc = new SolrInputDocument()` makes a new solr doc. Then I add fields to it (`id`, `name`, `title`, etc.). In this document only, I want to add the content of the pdf file. But when I fire the cURL request(as in the above code), it makes another new solr document with its own fields.

Comment: instead of using curl and new SolrInputDocument both you can just using curl to update the document or find an equivalent in SolrInputDocument.

Comment: Thats what my question was: I was wondering if there could be a curl request where instead of making an "all new" solr document and indexing file contents into it..if I could get the indexed content as a field or smth that I could then attach it to my previously declared solr document. Because, in my application, there's no scope of changing the code for SolrInputDocument. If anything could be changed, it must be change with the cURL request. So, I wanted to ask if I could arrange my cURL request somehow.

Comment: As in the ExtractingRequestHandler wiki, the examples given there: cURL request "always" creates a new solr document.

Comment: Solr allows partial updates of the document check http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/. However, am  not sure if it works with extract handler. But you can add rich document contents to the existing document.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at that also. But wasn't sure how to tweak it for my problem. Could you throw some light on how can one add `rich document contents to the existing document` using this partial update?

Comment: @Jayendra is it possible to pass that parameter `fmap.content` using this command? - `bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/sample.pdf`