# Index content of PDFs with Solr and Tika

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7, apache-tika, sitecore7.1

**The problem briefly**: I would like Sitecore to index the contents of PDFs using Solr's built in functionality (supplied by Tika).  I'm not sure how to configure Sitecore's indexing to use this feature in Solr(Tika).  (I think I need to write a custom indexer.)

I'm working with Sitecore 7 (7.1 Update 1) and want to index content from PDFs (or other rich media types).  I'd like to index this data for search purposes.

I have Solr (4.6.1) installed and working with Sitecore 7.  When I index my site it saves all of the documents to the correct Solr core, and I can successfully retrieve these documents for display.

Using `curl`, I can send a PDF to my Solr instance and get it indexed.

`curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal._id=doc1&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true" -F "myfile=@sample.pdf"`

This works, and I can read this content in my Sitecore web project and display it in views, so I know I can get access to this data.  However, I would like the data to be attached to the items that I have uploaded in Sitecore.

I'd like something like this to happen when I upload a PDF to the Sitecore Media Library and publish the item, or at least when I re-index the site.

I'm currently walking through the following tutorial to learn some things about writing custom indexing (here is a link to part 1):
http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2013/04/Sitecore-7-Search-Provider-Part-1-Manually-Triggered-Indexing.aspx

Thanks for you patience.

Answer (score 5):

For Sitecore, when handling media data, Lucene and Solr needed to index the content in a consistent way (so that you could switch between them if needed and still get data indexed in the same way). As Tika integration is very much a Solr thing it was decided that both should use the general windows concept of IFilters for indexing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter)

This means that as long as you have the correct IFilter for that mime type installed on the machine that is doing the indexing, then the '_content' computedfield will be populated with the output.

This doesn't mean you can't use the Solr Tika integration but it is not supported by default and would be a customization.

It would be very simple to:

1. Disable the '_content' computed field
2. Set up a publish pipeline processor that looks at each item being published
3. Check if it is a media item
4. Check to see if it is a PDF
5. Issues a command to push the content to your Solr server for indexing by Tika.

You may want to see what results you get by using an IFilter, if the results are close enough to what you want then you can go with that, if Tika is producing better results for you then you should be able to switch to that, although you would probably have your media content indexed in a separate Solr core so you would lose any Sitecore specific metadata around the document.

Some blog posts that might be helpful:

http://www.samjgriffin.com/blog/2013/11/06/sitecore-7-pdf-and-document-content-search/

http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/04/Sitecore-7-Indexing-Media-with-IFilters.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I second the recommendation to use Sitecore's built-in MediaItemContentExtractor + IFilter approach, unless you've already ruled that out for some reason ([IFilter difficulties, perhaps](http://www.samjgriffin.com/blog/2013/11/06/sitecore-7-pdf-and-document-content-search/)).  If an IFilter is not an option, or if you're interested in the other approach regardless, I would integrate Tika a little differently than Stephen suggested, though.

The tutorial you referenced deals with writing your own search provider - i.e. replacing the built-in provider entirely.  You should be able to leverage Sitecore's Solr provider and accomplish what you need with something lighter: a computed index field.  The built-in media extractor mentioned above uses this approach, which enables you to put just about anything into your index *during the normal indexing process*.  Here is a blog post from John West that walks through creating a basic computed index field: [Sitecore 7: Computed Index Fields](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/03/Sitecore-7-Computed-Index-Fields.aspx).

In short, write a class that implements `IComputedIndexField` and represents content extracted from PDFs or other rich documents.  In your implementation of the `ComputeFieldValue` method:

- Call `GetMediaStream()` on the document.
- Pass the stream to Solr in an [extract-only command](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Extract_Only) and capture the result.
- Return that result to store it in the computed index field.

If you need the media content to be in a particular existing index field, then configure the computed field as a [copy field (see 3.3.3)](http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2013/04/sitecore-7-in-depth-indexing-mechanics) into the existing field.  Otherwise, configure your search to reference the computed field.

The main drawback here is the expense of passing the extracted content back and forth, rather than committing it directly to the index in a single step.  Depending on your index size and contents, that may not be an issue for you.

One other potential option would be a post-rebuild task to add media content to the existing indexed documents.  I am not certain this would work.  It depends on knowing the IDs of the media items' documents and committing the rich document content in [partial document updates](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/), which [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609690/index-pdf-file-content-using-apache-solr) was unsuccessful in attempting.  If you try this, be sure to execute it in the indexing:end event prior to HTML cache clearing.

Whatever approach you take, if you want to work with Tika on a higher level than cURL, have a look at [SolrNet's implementation of ExtractCommand](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Commands/ExtractCommand.cs) and related classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you could upgrade your site into sitecore 7.2 in which the media items content will be indexed automatically and there is no need to install the related IFilter, You should read the following:
[Media Content Indexing in sitecore 7.2](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2014/03/media-content-indexing-updates-in-sitecore-72.aspx)